# Authenticate Service Account from Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth, service-accounts, google-groups-api

I'm trying to add members into a group using the API. I'm coding in the google script tool, however, I'm getting the error message:

```
{
     "error": {
         "errors": [
             {
                 "domain": "global",
                 "reason": "required",
                 "message": "Login Required",
                 "locationType": "header",
                 "location": "Authorization"
             }
         ],
         "code": 401,
         "message": "Login Required"
     }
}
```

I already added the scopes in the G SUITE domain, I already created service account, API key, OAuth 2.0 key.
My request is currently so:

```
  var headers = {
    "apiKey" : "****",
    "clientId" : "*****.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  }

  var payload = {
    "email": user,
    "role": "MEMBER"
  }

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload,
    "headers" : headers
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/***/members", options);
```

What is missing, or what am I doing wrong? I've read all the documentation and still can not figure out what's wrong.

Comment: You sure that's how you authorize with OAuth2? Pretty sure it isn't, even for a service account. Typical OAuth2 token consumption is in an explicit `Authorization` header, using a Bearer token.

Comment: So I am asking for help to see if this is correct or not, and also to know where I am wrong and how to adjust.

Comment: Looks like its not possible? https://support.google.com/a/forum/AAAA034zvV8hie_90GX5wg?hl=en

Comment: I found the solution, I posted the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was coding through Google Scripts, I found a service that has the function I need. It's called Directory and it's inside the Admin SDK section of Google. Below is the link that leads to the documentation, where you have the examples:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory

In the end, my code looked like this:

```
function insertMembers(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("")

  var membersInSheet = sheet.getRange(27, 3, sheet.getLastRow())
  var values = membersInSheet.getNumRows()
  var groupId = "email group"

  //Logger.log(membersInSheet)

  for (var i = 0; i < values; i++){
    var getMember = sheet.getRange(27+i, 3).getValue();

    var member = {
      email: getMember,
      role: 'MEMBER'
    };

    if (member != ''){
      var memberAdd = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupId);
      Logger.log(memberAdd);

    }
  }
}
```

No authentication, and no rest!

Comment: To be fair, it requires your personal authorization to execute the script, and the advanced service handles the oauth flow needed for the underlying AdminDirectory API calls.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this AdminDirectory is, only admin can use that application which is using AdminDierctory in backend. There is no option to access AdminDirectory when a normal user is using that app. Because application is authorized by different user. The only possible way is use OAuth2 APIs

Comment: Actually I was able to resolve the issue. The problem is, it missed the

"Accept": "application/json"